# $e^{Ax}=\cosh(x)I_{n}+\sinh(x)A$

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

Let $A\in\mathbb{M}_{n}$ such that $A^2=I_n$.

Show that for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$,

$$e^{Ax}=\cosh(x)I_{n}+\sinh(x)A$$.

Attempt:

$$\begin{align*}
        e^{xA}&=\begin{pmatrix}
        \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{(xa_{11})^{i}}{i!} & \cdots  & \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{(xa_{1n})^{i}}{i!} \\
        \vdots  & \ddots  & \vdots  \\
        \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{(xa_{n1})^{i}}{i!} & \cdots  & \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{(xa_{nn})^{i}}{i!} \\
        \end{pmatrix}\\
        &=\begin{pmatrix} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(a_{11}x)^{2k}}{(2k)!}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(a_{11}x)^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!} & \cdots  & \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(a_{1n}x)^{2k}}{(2k)!}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(a_{1n}x)^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!} \\ \vdots  & \ddots  & \vdots  \\ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(a_{n1}x)^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(a_{n1}x)^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!} & \cdots  & \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(a_{nn}x)^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(a_{nn}x)^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!} \\ \end{pmatrix}\\
        &=\begin{pmatrix} \cosh(x)a_{11}^{2k} & \cdots  & \cosh(x)a_{1n}^{2k} \\ \vdots  & \ddots  & \vdots  \\ \cosh(x)a_{n1}^{2k} & \cdots  & \cosh(x)a_{nn}^{2k} \\ \end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix} \sinh(x)a_{11}^{2k}a_{11} & \cdots  & \sinh(x)a_{1n}^{2k}a_{1n} \\ \vdots  & \ddots  & \vdots  \\ \sinh(x)a_{n1}^{2k}a_{n1} & \cdots  & \sinh(x)a_{nn}^{2k}a_{nn} \\ \end{pmatrix}\\
        &=\cos(x)A^{2k}+\sinh(x)A^{2k}A\\
        &=\cosh(x)I_{n}+\sinh(x)A.
    \end{align*}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: No, because you assume $(e^{xA})_{ij}=e^{xA_{ij}},\,(A^n)_{ij}=(A_{ij})^n$. Matrix exponentials are defined as [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the definition of the matrix exponential:
$$e^{Ax}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac {(Ax)^n}{n!}$$
$$e^{Ax}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac {(Ax)^{2n}}{(2n)!}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac {(Ax)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$
Now use the fact that $A^2=I_n \implies A^{2n}=I_n \text { and }  A^{2n+1}=A$.
$$\cosh (x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac {x^{2n}}{(2n)!}  \text{ and }\sinh (x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac {x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following DE:
$$ y'=Ay, y(0)=y_0 \tag1$$
for arbitrary $y_0\in R^n$.
This equation has a unique solution $y=e^{Ax}y_0$. Let
$$ y(x)=[\cosh(x)I_{n}+\sinh(x)A]y_0. $$
Then
$$ y'-Ay=[\sinh(x)I_n+\cosh(x)A]y_0-A[\cosh(x)I_{n}+\sinh(x)A]y_0=0, y(0)=y_0 $$
which implies that $y(x)$ is a solution of (1). By the uniqueness,
$$ e^{Ax}y_0=[\cosh(x)I_{n}+\sinh(x)A]y_0 $$
and hence
$$ e^{Ax}=\cosh(x)I_{n}+\sinh(x)A. $$